# Simplest way to make a live always-on display counter based on data from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, c, api

I'm a newbie to programming, but I am trying to write a simple program that shows on a dedicated screen a number which updates based on an API every so often.  So, the api will have one piece of data that will refresh every so often.

What is the best way to write a program that I can keep on screen which will show the updated counter in real time?

So, at 1pm the counter shows 1,000,000, then at 1:05 the counter shows 1,000,100.

I know a little bit of javascript and c, and html and css.  Is this something I could write as a webpage and keep open in Chrome?

Here is the output of the API in JSON:

{"company":{"id":2,"name":"location"},"total":8726110}

I want to put the TOTAL number into the h2 tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" >
    function loadscans() {

    $.getJSON('API URL')


    }

    </script>


</head>


<body>

<div id=“scans”><h2>scans</h2></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet? please provide us any attempts.

Comment: not yet, frankly I don't even know where to start haha.  I guess a good start would be to just have display the number in plain text html and have it refresh when i refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably going to be to set a timer on page load (look at javascript function setInterval) and every so often "poll" the server to get a new number to display using jquery ajax.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so depends on the entirety of your functional specifications, thus without that information there's no way to yield an appropriate answer to "What is the best way...?," since it is too broad and more of a design question than programmatic.

That aside, as mentioned earlier you can perform what's called polling, which performs the same process at an indicated interval.  In JavaScript you would typically accomplish this through `setInterval()` like so:

```
/* assumes function to get and set data are made */
var poller = setInterval(function() {
  var data = get_data();
  set_data(data);
}, 1000); /* polls at 1s intervals */
```

Or to throw in jQuery:

```
var poller = setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax("URL", {
    success: function(data) {
      set_data(data);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Another possibility is to use web sockets.  Web sockets provide a full duplex stream between the browser and your providing entity.  I don't think your particular application requires that level of complexity so I won't go into it, but I figured I would mention it since it's a popular solution to providing "live" data.

I think based on your admitted inexperience you should probably stick with the setInterval method, and using jQuery to wrap your XHR would hide a lot of the inner workings you probably don't care about.

These are just examples, though.  To do it this way you'll probably want to utilize timeouts and a few other supporting aspects.

To get a more concrete answer you should work out the functionality you wish to create and ask a more specific question.